# Auto play for USB External Hard Drive keeps popping up

Tags: autoplay

I also have a 2 TB Seagate External hard drive and the auto play keeps popping up about every 30 minutes. Does this mean my drive is unstable and on the way to crashing? Is there a way to stop this from continually happening?? And YES - I have tried other USB ports and I have about 8 other External hard drives going and none of them have ever done this.

Any ideas or answers would be appreciated

Comment: Do you hear the "new device discovered sound" before the autoplay pop-up is shown again?

Answer (score 1):

IF you have Vista or Windows 7, go to the Control Panel and using the search function type auto, the first result is the entry for controlling that behavior, take notice that it will work for ALL drives, yeah something is lose on that hard drive a false contact.